# Printing a calendar with Chinese characters in Month and day using Python

Tags: python

Below is my code:

```
import calendar

chinese = calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(6, "CHINESE")

chinese.pryear(2016)
```

The calendar printed out is not able to display the month and day in Chinese characters.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://www.pgbovine.net/unicode-python.htm

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the OS you are using? In Ubuntu 14.04.4, both python 2.7 and 3.x works, creating the calendar with `calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(6,"zh_CN.UTF-8")`.

Comment: I am using Windows 10, what you have suggested works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chinese = calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(6, "zh_CN.UTF-8")
```

`CHINESE` is not local set, you should serve a correct local, `zh_CN.UTF-8` will work. Good luck!